# Issue with the page size with jspdf in react

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, jspdf

I have to do an export pdf with jspdf and i have an issue with the size, i use also hmtl2canva to put my html in the page. The issue is when i put a fixed size my of a 96dpi pdf so 1123*794 it's good when i have a 100% zoom on the page it looks good but when i change the zoom it's not good so i don't understand why. That's my code :

```
import "./App.css";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import { ResponsiveBar } from "@nivo/bar";
import { ResponsivePie } from "@nivo/pie";
import data from "./data";
import data2 from "./data2";
import image from "./points-forts.png";
import image2 from "./points-de-progres.png";
import Chip from '@mui/material/Chip';

const App = () => {
  const pdf = new jsPDF("portrait", "px", "A4");
  const printDocument = () => {
    const input = document.getElementById("divToPrint");
    html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      pdf.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 0, 0);
      // pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
      pdf.save("download.pdf");
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <div
          id="divToPrint"
          className="mt4"
          style={{ height: "1123px", width: "794px" }}
        >
          <div style={{ margin: "20px", backgroundColor: "#FCFCFE" }}>
            <div
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "#581F64",
                height: "100px",
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                borderRadius: "20px",
                marginBottom: "40px",
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{ fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: "bold", color: "white" }}
              >
                LHH
              </div>
              <div
                style={{
                  fontSize: "14px",
                  color: "white",
                  margin: "0 10px",
                  textAlign: "center"
                }}
              >
                <div>RAPPORT DE PRISE DE REFERENCE</div>
                <div>John Doe - Directeur Financier</div>
                <div>Date d’édition : 01/02/2023</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="square border">
                <div className="title">Résultats sur les compétences</div>
                <div style={{ height: "70%", width: "100%", marginTop: "5%" }}>
                  <ResponsiveBar
                    data={data}
                    keys={["hot dog"]}
                    indexBy="country"
                    margin={{ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 30 }}
                    layout="horizontal"
                    padding={0.3}
                    valueScale={{ type: "linear" }}
                    indexScale={{ type: "band", round: true }}
                    colors="#581F64"
                    labelTextColor="#FFFFFFDE"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="square">
                <div className="title2">Points Forts</div>
                <div style={{ height: "65%", marginTop: "5%" }}>
                  <img src={image} alt="logo" style={{ height: "100%" }}></img>
                </div>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
                  <Chip label="Fidélisation" className="tag yellow"></Chip>
                  <Chip label="Réactivité" className="tag yellow"></Chip>
                  <Chip label="Gestion des conflits" className="tag yellow"></Chip>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="square ">
                <div className="title3">Points de progrès</div>
                <div style={{ height: "65%", marginTop: "5%" }}>
                  <img src={image2} alt="logo" style={{ height: "100%" }}></img>
                </div>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
                  <Chip label="Fidélisation" className="tag green"></Chip>
                  <Chip label="Réactivité" className="tag green"></Chip>
                  <Chip label="Gestion des conflits" className="tag green"></Chip>
                </div></div>
              <div className="square border">
                <div className="title">Recommandez-vous ce candidat ? </div>
                <div style={{ height: "70%", width: "100%", marginTop: "5%" }}>
                  <ResponsivePie
                    data={data2}
                    margin={{ top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 10, left: 30 }}
                    innerRadius={0.5}
                    padAngle={0.7}
                    cornerRadius={3}
                    activeOuterRadiusOffset={8}
                    borderWidth={1}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style={{display : 'flex', height : '150px', flexDirection:'column'}}>
              <div className="titleRef"> 8 Référents ont répondu</div>
              <div className="listeRep">Besnier Robin - L’Oréal - N+1, Renaudin Nathan - Spotify - Manager, Mallet NaÏm - Spotify - Collègue, Référent anonyme, Bourgeois Romane – Zalando – Collègue, Silvestre Tom – L’Oréal – Manager, Référent anonyme</div>
            </div>
            <div style={{marginTop : '8%', display : 'flex', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
              <div className="lhhFooter">LHH</div>
              <div style={{marginLeft : '7%'}}>page 1/2</div>
              <div className="coss">Fourni par COSS by 5Feedback</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* fin du document a print  */}
        </div>
        <div className="mb5">
          <button onClick={printDocument}>Print</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

100% zoom on the page  :[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TrW6.png)

70% : [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd4Y7.png)